# Access Security. Stop a database from being copied to another computer

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, code-access-security

I have a database solution that can be sold to clients but I don't want a client to then pass on that database to someone else.  Much like MS office won't install on more than one machine.
Is it possible to have an AutoExec run that would check that a computer's unique identifier matches one hardcoded into the database?  If it doesn't match then the database closes. 
Or is there a better option/way of achieving what I need?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest KeyedAccess which requires a key for each install that you provide. http://www.peterssoftware.com/ka.htm

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look.